# common lisp and emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to install common lisp on an Ubuntu system with no success so far . I'm newbie in emacs and linux . I tried using lispbox by downloading the tar ball and running sh lispbox.sh command but the shell reports Bad substitution error . What I need is step-by-step instruction on how to get common lisp running with emacs so that I can start programming .

Answer (score 6):

1. Use your package manager to install SBCL (Steel Bank Common Lisp).
2. Download Quicklisp from http://quicklisp.org.  There are complete instructions there, but I shall try to filter the important steps:
3. Run `sbcl --load "quicklisp.lisp"`.
4. At the SBCL prompt, run `(quicklisp-quickstart:install)`.
5. At the SBCL prompt, run `(ql:add-to-init-file)` (press Enter to confirm).
6. At the SBCL prompt, run `(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")`.  This will create a file that you can load in your `.emacs` to setup Slime.

Now you can open your Emacs, do `M-x slime` and hack away.  Be sure to read the documentation for Quicklisp and Slime.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to [https://portacle.github.io/](https://gist.github.com/lisp-is-the-future/b1cdefe877fbb5f61bbb4b020618a757) (a newer lispbox-like ready-to-use emacs/SLIME-sbcl-quicklisp system).
2. download and install it and start it following instructions there.

For ubuntu 64 bit:

```
wget https://github.com/portacle/portacle/releases/download/1.2b/lin-portacle.tar.xz
tar xJf lin-portacle.tar.xz
cd portacle
./portacle.run
# enjoy :)
```

[Minimal set of commands needed to program common lisp in SLIME by me](https://gist.github.com/lisp-is-the-future/b1cdefe877fbb5f61bbb4b020618a757)